# jQuery selector parents and siblings

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` structure that I can't change.
In an `outer-container` are two `inner-container`s.
I want to toggle the `inner-container2`.
The button is in the first `inner-container`.

This structure repeats again and again. So I can't select the classname (`inner-container2`). This classname appears often.

I must select something like:
go one level up from the button and take the next `div`

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container1">
    <div class="button">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container2">
  </div>
</div>
```

This group comes again and again.

I want to have a script that starts with a click on button
and opens only the `inner-container2` in the same group.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
  $('?????').toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.inner-container2{
  background-color:gray;
  height : 50px;
  width : 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container1">
    <div class="button">
      <button>BUTTON1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container2"></div>
</div>
```

I have made an example using your code just added css to define the functionality.